# Using a specific network adapter for a service

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, connection, service, windows-service

On a Synology NAS this is called: Service-interface binding

Is there something to specify the network adapter used by a certain service? I don't wan't all applications running on that adapter. I only wan't to run a few on that network adapter.

Else I would have to run a VM to get the same solution.

Comment: There are to less Details to do a propper and 100% suitable answer. As a 2nd answer:
May you consider adding different vlans to your network adapter and add persistent routes on your host. Just an idea you can think about

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is no such thing in Windows built-in.

Now even if you can bind a certain service to a particular interface, that doesn't stop other services to use that interface. Then actually you need to bind each and every service to certain interface so that they don't use any other than the one configured.

I'm also not quite sure, what do you mean by, application running on an adapter. An application can uses an interface to communicate to outside world using TCP/IP (or some other protocol). May be you should think of securing that communication.

As of binding a certain `server socket` to an interface only works for incoming traffic and not for outgoing traffic. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065495/using-a-specific-network-interface-for-a-socket-in-windows

May be you should think of certain services to be available on certain ip addresses to secure them.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am talking about Windows. I meant that Synology has such a feature, and I would like to know if Windows has the same solution.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Windows will attempt to send all traffic on what it has enumerated as the first interface. If that fails it will try alternates in order. The only way you might be able to pull it off, is running one service over IPv4 and the other on IPv6 and then disable the alternate protocol on the other interface. I have not tried this, but it may work with MS's broken networking.

Answer (score 0):

For outgoing traffic, no.  It's possible to prioritize which adapter/address is used by default by Windows for outgoing traffic, but not for a specific service.

For incoming traffic, you could register a DNS record for the network adapter/address, the clients would use that name to connect to your service. If you want to prevent the other adapters/addresses from receiving traffic for that service, a firewall may be an option. As far as what address the service binds to, that would be application-dependent.  For example, with IIS or WCF it's possible to bind a service to a specific address.